# How can I extend the root/filesystem to take unallocated space?

Tags: ubuntu, partition, root-filesystem, move-partition

This is what my partitions look like. The first one is the `/root` partition that I need to extend, second one is the `/home` partition and the third is the `unallocated` space that I want to add to the `/root`. How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s a good idea to take backups of any data on your computer that you cannot afford to lose before doing this. It’s not dangerous but it is possible to mess up and lose data.

You need to boot your system into a live environment that has GParted included. An Ubuntu installation iso is ideal or there is also a GParted live iso available. Once booted run GParted

Once you have done that you need to move partition 2 all the way to the right and click apply. This will take some time so be patient. That step moves the unallocated space between partitions 1 and 2.

Next you will be able to expand partition 1 and click apply, making use of all the unallocated space. This should be quite quick.

That’s it! Good luck

Link to similar question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions